# How can I make the MySqlSessionStateProvider use cookies in my .NET MVC app?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, session-state

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="Custom" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="App_Name" description="App_Description" connectionStringName="MySqlSession" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="True" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I have the MySqlSession connection string defined in the ConnectionStrings section in the web.config.

When I run the site, the sessions table in the database is not being populated. However, if I add `cookieless=true` to the customProvider the sessions table is populated but then the session string is shown in the URL. I do not want to show the sessions string in the URL as this interferes with my load balancer. How can I get the MySqlSessionStateStore to work with cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have misidentified the problem. I only need the authentication to persist in my load balancer. I solved this by making sure the machine key on each IIS instance was the same.

The sessionState listed above was completely removed as I am not storing anything custom in session.